# A generalization to Bott‘s theorem (from Milnor’s “Morse theory”)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

This is Theorem 22.1 of Milnor‘s Morse theory:

> Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, let $p,q\in M$ be so that the space $\Omega’$ of minimal geodesics joining $p$ to $q$ is a topological manifold, and every such geodesic has Morse index $\geq c$. Then $\pi_i(\Omega’)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_i(\Omega)$ for $i\leq c-2$, where $\Omega$ is the space of curves joining $p$ to $q$.

For example, let $M$ be the round $n$-sphere, $p,q$ be the north and south pole, then $\Omega’$ is the $n-1$ sphere.

Is there a generalisation to this theorem, in which we replace $\{p,q\}$ by some closed curve $\gamma$ in $M$, $\Omega’$ by the space (which should assumed to be a manifold) of area-minimising disks in $M$ with boundary $\gamma$, and $\Omega$ by the space of disk in $M$ with boundary $\gamma$?